# Trying to insert massive URL query into SQL

Tags: php, sql, database, forms

I have looked around a lot of tutorials and post on this website.

I have been asked to design a rather massive php form that will take a lot of information of users and insert into a database.

I wish to divide this into many pages (maybe 4 or 5 page).

I am not looking for code, but rather the best practice for this.

I was thinking **IN THEORY CODE**

```
    > Show page one
    >>user inputs details
    >>>tempDatabaseTable takes info
    >>>>next page
    >>>>>.....
    >>>>>page5 (last page)
    >>>>>>when all information has been collected, query from tempDatabaseTable and insert         
    >>>>>>into relevant tables.
    >>>>>>>delete tempDatabaseTable
```

I am wondering, I know I should use the $get method so info not displayed in URL, but whats the best way to transfer the information (Array, JSON) etc.

I am only starting php and SQL , but so far have been using data through the URL as information would only be used on local network.

Again, this will be a huge , huge amount of questions, (its 9 a4 pages)

Bear in mind a lot of the fields will be dynamically created as users may need more rows for some questions EG - Your brothers name(s). If they have to brothers they will click the add more button to dynamically create new form field.

Any good tuts would be really great.

Comment: look for pagination on this website. Lots of questions about this topic.

Comment: You probably mean `POST` instead of `$get`. If not, you should use `POST` so that the info is not displayed in the url.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , I am using mySQL through php if that helps ?.

Comment: @jeroen , Thanks a mill, Silly mistake to write, I did of course mean the post method.

Comment: @John , thanks John. I will try that now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about working with sessions?

You could consider using a **session array** to store the information. It would allow you to hold onto each page's inputs and query it all at once on the last page.

Note: I don't know that this is best practice or not, but I don't really know of a more effective way of moving information from page to page without either:

A: using $_GET (which is generally not a good option)
B: appending each previous $_POST to the next page's $_POST array (which might break if the user bounces back and forth)

If you do go this route, however, always keep in mind security risks such as session hijacking. Best to use https if possible when working with sensitive information.

Tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php
Further Reading: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Thanks for the link @Jesse Kernaghan , I will look into it now.